# Getting Error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After importing the zip project in android studio, I am getting the following error:-

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
Required by:
:Parse-Server-Starter-Project:unspecified
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File

My Gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
 }

}
allprojects {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

}

ext {

compileSdkVersion = 22
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

minSdkVersion = 9
targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. in repositories tag add google(),
2. also comment buildtoolsversion = '23.0.1'
3. compilesdkversion and targetsdkversion must be same.

Kindly do the changes and let us know.

Comment: I added tag google(), commented the buildtoolsversion = '23.0.1' and made targetsdk version same as compilesdkversion. But now there is another big error coming  as-        Build file 'C:\Users\BISWA\Downloads\parseproject\Parse-Server-Starter-Project\build.gradle' line: 5

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Parse-Server-Starter-Project'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: can u share the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file

Comment: URL is  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Comment: change it to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip or update to higher version

Comment: Now another error is coming :(     
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Parse-Server-Starter-Project'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.